# Is there standard notation for a set of indexed families?

Tags: notation, index-notation

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be an index set, and $E$ another set.

I have a set $A$ of tuples which I don't know how to express. Each contains both a subset of $\mathcal{I}$ ("domains") and a [family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family) of values in $E$ indexed by this very subset:

\begin{align}
\forall a = (a_0,\ a_1) \in A,\quad a_0 &\subset \mathcal{I}\\
a_1 &= (v_i \in E)_{i \in a_0}
\end{align}

How to write $A$ then?
$A = 2^\mathcal{I} \times ?$
$A = 2^\mathcal{I} \times E^\mathcal{I}\ ?$
$A = 2^\mathcal{I} \times E_\mathcal{I}\ ?$
$A = \mathcal{I} : E_{|\mathcal{I}}\ ?$

Comment: We may start rewriting $A = \{ (a_0, a_1) \mid a_0 \subseteq  \mathcal I \text { and } a_1= \{ v_i \in E \mid i \in a_0 \} \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA This does work. Should I understand that there is no such "set of families" notation? :)

Comment: I do not said that :-)

Comment: For $a_0$, being a subset of $\mathcal I$, it is an element of the [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $\mathcal I$. So the symbol $2^{\mathcal I}$ is fine.